# wait for angular app to be fully rendered from phantom script

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I'm writing a script which generates png images from every page of my frontend.
I'm using angular for the UI and capturing the pages with phantom.

The view take a while until angular finish rendering it so I have to wait *a little* before capturing:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:9000/', function () {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    page.render('snapshot.png');
    phantom.exit();
  }, 2000);
});
```

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this. I found angular can emit an event when the page is fully rendered:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
  // do something
});
```

And found a way for communicate to phantom with `onCallback` so I could write something like:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
  window.callPhantom({ hello: 'world' });
});
```

Then in other place in phantom script:

```
page.onCallback = function() {
  page.render('snapshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
};
```

But I'm lost in how to inject the angular `$viewContentLoaded` handle from the phantom script.

I don't know if `evaluate`/`evalueateAsyn` are the way to go ...

```
page.evaluateAsync(function () {
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    window.callPhantom({ hello: 'world' });
  });
});
```

Maybe I could access the right `$scope` in some way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The associated PhantomJS API is `onCallback`; you can [find the API doc on the wiki](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).

```javascript
// in angular
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
  window.callPhantom();
});

// in the phantomjs script
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onCallback = function() {
  page.render('snapshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
};
page.open('http://localhost:9000/');
```

You can get access to the `$rootScope` by accessing the injector; for example, if you're using the `ng-app` directive, you can find the element with the directive and call `.injector().get("$rootScope")` on it. However, I'm not sure if the `$viewContentLoaded` event will already have fired by then.

Comment: my question is about injecting the angular code in the phantom script since I don't want to mix test dependencies in the frontend source

Comment: @PauFracés I see; I've updated with a bit more info--hope it helps.

Comment: "you can find the element with the directive and call" sorry, but I don't know how to do this

Comment: @PauFracés If you're using jQuery it's `$('[ng-app]')` to get the element (then call `.injector()`, on it, so `$('[ng-app]').injector().get("$rootScope")`)

Comment: @MichelleTilley Is it available access page/phantom variables inside onCallback function?

Comment: Can you put this all together for us? What does the page.evaluate block look like?