# Is there a way to listen to an event in the phantom context from page context?

Tags: javascript, events, phantomjs, hook, html

For example: I open a page with PhantomJS, evaluate an asynchronous script (e.g. ajax). When it succeeds, I want to let the phantom context (outside of `page.evaluate()`) know that the asynchronous process is finished.

I don't want to use `setTimeout` and `setInteval` to wait and check continously in the phantom context that the process is finished.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is exactly what the [`onCallback` and `window.callPhantom()` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html) is for.

So, if you have an asynchronous call in the page context like an AJAX request, you can do this:

```
page.onCallback = function(data){
    console.log("finished: " + data.text);
    phantom.exit();
};
page.evaluate(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
        if (this.readyState === DONE){
            window.callPhantom({text: this.responseText});
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
});
```

The other way to use this is to add the call to your production JavaScript to make testing easier. If you're writing a web application it is sometimes complicated to find a selector which denotes when a page is fully loaded. To make testing such an application easier, you can have something like this in the page JavaScript:

```
finishOffPage(function callback(){
    if (typeof window.callPhantom === "function") {
        window.callPhantom({type: "loadFinished"});
    }
});
```

Then you can write tests like this:

```
page.onCallback = function(data){
    if (data.type === "loadFinished") {
        // do some testing
    }
};
page.open(url);
```

This is an example where such a thing can be added dynamically: [wait for angular app to be fully rendered from phantom script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604618/wait-for-angular-app-to-be-fully-rendered-from-phantom-script)

Comment: I'm using Node.js along with phantom to make my app. Suppose there are two concurrent requests from users. Each request runs the above code once. Is there any possibility that page.onCallback of the first request receive data from window.callPhantom() of the second request?

Comment: @MrCold Not really, because you wouldn't use the same `page` instance for both requests even if you use the same PhantomJS instance. Even if you do use the same `page` instance, it still won't be possible, because you cannot register two event handlers to the same event. You will probably need some middleware to route the results to the appropriate response objects.

Comment: @ArtjomB. in your example `if (typeof window.callPhantom == "Function") {` suppose to be `if (typeof window.callPhantom === "function") {`, so lower case "function".

Comment: @Grigory You're completely right. I wonder how nobody noticed this.